# What are the definitions for the Outlander PHEV Routine Maintenance schedules?

Tags: mitsubishi, scheduled-maintenance

I have a 2019 Mitsubishi Outlander PHEV.  It's possible to change the "Routine Maintenance" window on the vehicle to numerous settings.  However, they have not so descriptive names like "Normal", "Severe", "AU", "JPN 10".  Does anyone know what the corresponding settings are for each of these abbreviations?

EDIT:  There appear to be multiple options under each selection that can be edited from the "Clear" screen.  For instance, "NORMAL" has both a 13000 miles / 5 months option and a 20500 miles / 11 month option.  "SEVERE" has 9200 miles / 2 months and 13000 miles / 5 months.

Comment: Have you looked in the Owners Manual for the vehicle?

Comment: The abbreviated owners manual makes no mention of either.  The full PDF manual (online) doesn't get any relevant hits when searching through it for the abbreviations.

Comment: I would contact a Mitsubishi dealer. That is just crazy they give no explanation in the owners manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the region to the area where you use the car - different countries have different recommended service intervals. Your dealer can tell you which one they use, but you can always override it if you want. This only relates to when the idiot light appears on the dashboard, and nothing else.

JPN = Japan

NAS = (not sure if this is North America, or North Africa and Sahel)

EU = European Union

AUS = Australasia

GCC = Gulf Cooperation Council

Available settings are:

JPN10 - 12000 KM / 12 MONTH

JPN11 - 12000 KM / 6 MONTH

JPN20 - 12000 KM / 6 MONTH

JPN30 - 12000 KM / 12 MONTH

JPN31 - 12000 KM / 6 MONTH

JPN40 - 12000 KM / 3 MONTH

NAS10 - 12000 KM / 6 MONTH

NAS11 - 12000 KM / 3 MONTH

NAS20 - 12000 KM / 6 MONTH

NAS21 - 12000 KM / 4 MONTH

EU10 - 12000 KM / 12 MONTH

EU11 - 12000 KM / 12 MONTH

AUS - 12000 KM / 12 MONTH

GCC - 12000 KM / 6 MONTH

OPTION - OFF

Servicing is based on distance driven, or time elapsed since last service - whichever comes first.

Normal and Severe relate to the type of driving you do. If you drive on freeways t constant speed, and not a lot of short trips, it's called 'Normal'. If you idle a lot or do a lot of short journeys where the car doesn't warm up, it will be classed as 'Severe', and will need more frequent maintenance.

Comment: This list isn't exhaustive/complete, especially since many entries have multiple versions underneath, but it is more complete than anything else I have found.